# React: TypeError: _ref undefined - when converting from stateless to class based component

Tags: reactjs

I had a functional React Component that looked like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const expand = (itemId) => {
    alert('item ' + itemId + ' clicked!');
}

const Item = ({itemData: {id, title, thumbnail}}) => {
    let hasThumb = !(thumbnail === 'self' || thumbnail === 'nsfw');
    return (
        <div className="item" onClick={() => expand(id)}>
            <h3 className="item-title">{title}</h3>
            <img className="item-thumbnail" src={hasThumb ? thumbnail: 'placeholder.png'}
                alt={hasThumb ? 'Item thumbail' : 'Placeholder thumbnail'} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Item;
```

It works perfectly!  But I want to add functionality that will require me to make it stateful/change it to a class-based Component structure.  I did it like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Item extends Component {

    expand = (itemId) => {
        alert('item ' + itemId + ' clicked!');
    }

    render() {
        let hasThumb = !(this.props.itemData.thumbnail === 'self' || this.props.itemData.thumbnail === 'nsfw');
        return (
            <div className="item" onClick={() => this.expand(this.props.itemData.id)}>
                <h3 className="item-title">{this.props.itemData.title}</h3>
                <img className="item-thumbnail" src={hasThumb ? this.props.itemData.thumbnail: 'placeholder.png'}
                    alt={hasThumb ? 'Item thumbail' : 'Placeholder thumbnail'} />
            </div>
        );
    };

}

export default Item;
```

It compiles perfectly with no errors, but in the browser I get `TypeError: _ref is undefined` and it calls out the line number for the render definition.  I found that removing the destructuring statement in the render argument makes this go away (I can refer to everything as `this.props.data.[whatever]`) but this is inconvenient compared with being able to destructure, as I'm able to do in a functional React component.  What have I done wrong here?  Or is destructuring in this way simply not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, for class based component destructuring is done inside the method.

eg:

```
render() {
      let { itemData: {id, title, thumbnail} } = this.props;
      .....
}


componentDidMount() {
      let { itemData: {id, title, thumbnail} } = this.props;
      .....
}
```